# Pandas to_csv to GzipFile in Python 3 not working

Tags: python, pandas

Saving a Pandas dataframe to gzipped csv in memory works like this in Python 2.7 (Pandas 0.22.0):

```
from io import BytesIO
import gzip
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
s = BytesIO()
f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=s, mode='wb', filename='file.csv')
df.to_csv(f)
s.seek(0)
content = s.getvalue()
```

However, in Python 3.6 (Pandas 0.22.0), the same code throws error when calling `to_csv`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1524, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1652, in save
    self._save()
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1740, in _save
    self._save_header()
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1708, in _save_header
    writer.writerow(encoded_labels)
  File "miniconda3/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 260, in write
    data = memoryview(data)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How should I resolve this? Do I need to alter the `GzipFile` object somehow for `to_csv` to handle it properly?

To clarify, I want to create the gzipped file in-memory (the `content` variable) so that I can save it to Amazon S3 using [Boto 3 `put_object`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) later.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thanks for your comment, I added some more code and clarified the use case :)

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise `StringIO`:

```
from io import StringIO
buf = StringIO()
df.to_csv(buf)
f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=s, mode='wb', filename='file.csv')
f.write(buf.getvalue().encode())
f.flush()
```

Note also the added `f.flush()` - according to my experience without this line the `GzipFile` may in some cases randomly not flush the data, resulting in corrupt archive.

Or as a complete example based on your code:

```
from io import BytesIO
import gzip
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
s = BytesIO()
buf = StringIO()
f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=s, mode='wb', filename='file.csv')
df.to_csv(buf)
f.write(buf.getvalue().encode())
f.flush()
s.seek(0)
content = s.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Roland Pihlakas works, except the gzip file is incomplete (despite the flush). It needs to be closed before calling bytesio.getvalue(). Modified code:

```
with BytesIO() as b:
    with StringIO() as s, GzipFile(fileobj=b, mode='wb') as gz:
        df.to_csv(s, encoding="utf-8")
        gz.write(s.getvalue().encode())
        gz.flush()
    b.seek(0)
    csv_bytes = b.getvalue()
```